# Use placeholder value for passwords in web forms

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, passwords

My ASP.NET Core MVC application stores credential passwords provided by the user to access other resources. This means the password needs to be stored in plain text in the database, but as with all passwords, it should not be displayed to the user when editing the configuration. (I include reading the source code of the page. Using developer tools to quickly inspect a pre-filled password field is something a technically skilled user can easily do.) The password can also be cleared which needs to be distinguished. Also, the user should be able to see whether a password was set or not. The input field is masked: `<input type="password">` (But the HTML source is of course not.)

In order to let the user see whether a password was set, but not to see the password itself, I usually use an invalid placeholder/replacement value when filling the form for display. In PHP I often use a string of spaces only, and a fixed length. This gives the impression that a password has been entered, but it's not really there. In the POST request I check whether this field consists of spaces only and don't change the password in the stored data. If the user has removed all spaces, then the field will be empty and I delete the stored password.

ASP.NET Core MVC doesn't let me do this however. When the user provides a string of spaces only, the model binding gives me a `null` value instead. It does some implicit trimming and then entire removal of the value for me. (`Request.Form["MyPassword"]` still contains the original spaces.) So it's a bit impractical to use this approach with ASP.NET. I'm also reluctant to define an arbitrary "never used" password as the replacement string because the user might enter this as the real password. You never know.

So what would be a good approach here to indicate password presence but not actually send it with the form?

Answer (score 1):

The most transparent way would be to have some text above the field saying "The password is already set, inputting something into this field will change that password." in a noticeable box (red background for example). Being clear is the best way.

Be sure to set `autocomplete="off"` on the password field to avoid password managers messing with the value. This doesn't work in Firefox, though - the solution would be to mark the field as readonly and revert that on click (with JavaScript).

Also, don't store passwords in plain text. There are many excellent hashing libraries for C#.

Comment: A separate info box is an interesting idea, hadn't though of that yet. Why should Firefox ignore the `autocomplete="off"` attribute? As I said, I can't store it in a hashed form this time because an external service (here an MQTT server) requires it in plain text. My own authentication passwords are stored in a properly hashed form, of course. :-)

Comment: @ygoe I've had issues with this attribute in Firefox in the past, I think it's just not implemented well. Your experience may be different, though.